# ICE Emergency Contacts on Emergency Dialer Screen

Tags: phone-app, emergency-calls

On my Samsung Galaxy S 4, I can add contacts to the "ICE - emergency contacts" group. When I initiate the emergency dialer, there are four gray buttons with plus signs. Pressing any one of them brings up a list of the contacts I added to that group.

Each of the buttons acts the same. I would think that you should be able to assign one contact per button and have the button show a name or relation.

Is it possible to do this? How?

[image: emergency dialer]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you hit the gray box & that ICE list pops up, I believe you just have to select a contact from that list in order to assign that person/phone number to the box.

Just be careful with assigning contacts to the gray boxes because it can be very easy to pocket dial these people. In case you're interested in removing someone from the gray box, you select the menu button while on the "Emergency Dialer" screen & it'll give the option to remove the contact from the gray box.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Just a wild guess:

- Open Contacts app
- Long-press a contact so that a menu appears
- Click Edit
- Click Groups
- Check ICE - emergency contacts

*Although I have an S4, I can't try it on my phone due to some security settings.*

Comment: Yes, that's the part I've done - as indicated in the first sentence of my question.

Answer (score 1):

While phone is locked, hit the "Emergency call" option, when it opens hit the settings/menu (left of the home button) on the device. You will see "Remove" appear at the bottom of the screen. Select "Remove" then you will see checkboxes next to the contacts. Select the contacts to be removed and then check the "Check Mark" at the top right side of the screen. This will remove those contacts from there, but not from your ICE group.

Comment: That works for removing assignments to the button, but my question, which has been answered, was how to *make* the assignments.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Contacts → Groups and you will see a group named "ICE - Emergency Contacts". Add your emergency numbers there and now you can access them from outer screen.

Comment: That does not address the question, which has been answered, of how to attach individual contacts to each button.